# Field repository required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, gradle, spring-data-jpa, build.gradle

I have spent some days trying to solve this error but without success. I am trying to configure two databases and write in both of them.

I looked at:

https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-multiple-database-configuration

https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2015/10/31/configuring-multiple-jpa-entity-managers-in-spring-boot/

https://github.com/igormukhin/spring-boot-sample-data-jpa-multiple/blob/master/src/main/java/sample/data/jpa/Database1Configuration.java
And a loot more links from SO for the errors or similar examples.

Here is my code:

```
fromDB.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:D:/test1/db1
fromDB.datasource.username=sa
fromDB.datasource.password=
fromDB.datasource.platform=h2
fromDB.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver

toDB.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:D:/test2/db2
toDB.datasource.username=sa
toDB.datasource.password=
toDB.datasource.platform=h2
toDB.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.h2.console.settings.trace=true
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Hibernate Settings -hibernate.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

ConfigClasses

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "toEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "toTransactionManager",
        basePackages = "leadTime.service"
    )
    public class ToDBConfig {

      @Bean
      @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "toDB.datasource")
      public DataSource toDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder
            .create()
            .build();
      }

      @Bean(name = "toEntityManager")
      public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean toEntityManagerFactory(
          EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
            .dataSource(toDataSource())
            .properties(hibernateProperties())
            .packages(TestDataTo.class)
            .persistenceUnit("to")
            .build();
      }

      @Bean(name = "toTransactionManager")
      public PlatformTransactionManager toTransactionManager(@Qualifier("toEntityManager") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
      }

      private Map hibernateProperties() {

        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("hibernate.properties");

        try {
          Properties properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);

          return properties.entrySet().stream()
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                  e -> e.getKey().toString(),
                  e -> e.getValue())
              );
        } catch (IOException e) {
          return new HashMap();
        }
      }
    }
```

Second configClass

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "fromEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "fromTransactionManager",
        basePackages = "leadTime.service"
    )
    public class FromDBConfig {

      @Primary
      @Bean
      @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "fromDB.datasource")
      public DataSource fromDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder
            .create()
            .build();
      }

      @Primary
      @Bean(name = "fromEntityManager")
      public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean fromEntityManagerFactory(
          EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
            .dataSource(fromDataSource())
            .properties(hibernateProperties())
            .packages(TestDataFrom.class)
            .persistenceUnit("from")
            .build();
      }

      @Primary
      @Bean(name = "fromTransactionManager")
      public PlatformTransactionManager fromTransactionManager(@Qualifier("fromEntityManager") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
      }

      private Map hibernateProperties() {

        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("hibernate.properties");

        try {
          Properties properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);

          return properties.entrySet().stream()
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                  e -> e.getKey().toString(),
                  e -> e.getValue())
              );
        } catch (IOException e) {
          return new HashMap();
        }
      }}
```

Repository:

```
    public interface ToRepository extends CrudRepository<TestDataTo, Integer> 
    {

      @Override
      TestDataTo save(TestDataTo testDataTo);
    }
```

DataInit:

```
    @Component
    public class DataInit {
      @Autowired
      ToRepository toRepository;

      @Autowired
      FromRepository fromRepository;

      @Transactional("fromTransactionManager")
      public void insertDataIntoFromDB() throws SQLException {
        TestDataFrom testDataFrom = new TestDataFrom();
        testDataFrom.setId(1);
        testDataFrom.setName("Test");
        fromRepository.save(testDataFrom);

      }
      //
      @Transactional("toTransactionManager")
      public void insertDataIntoToDB() throws SQLException {

        TestDataTo testDataTo = new TestDataTo();
        testDataTo.setId(1);
        testDataTo.setName("Ale");
        toRepository.save(testDataTo);
      }
    }
```

MainClass:

```
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class LeadTimeApplication  {
      private Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger("LeadTimeApplication");

      @Autowired
      ToRepository toRepository;

      @Autowired
      FromRepository fromRepository;

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LeadTimeApplication.class, args);

      }

      @Autowired DataInit initializer;

      @PostConstruct
      public void init() throws  SQLException{

        initializer.insertDataIntoFromDB();
        initializer.insertDataIntoToDB();

      }
```

Error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field toRepository in leadTime.LeadTimeApplication 
required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

I tried:
Using

`@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class})`

Honestly, I don't know what else to do, I re-wrote this code so many times using different approaches but without success. If I let spring to his job, without configuring new entityManagers and transactions and without using `@Transactional`, the application is working (2 DBs are created), but both tables are created in the sameDB (of course)

Added gradle config

```
//Spring dependencies
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter- 
actuator:${springBootVersion}"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter- 
web:${springBootVersion}"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter- 
logging:${springBootVersion}"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration- 
processor:${springBootVersion}"


//JPA dependency
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data- 
jpa:${springBootVersion}"

testCompile "com.oracle:ojdbc7:12.1.0.2"
testCompile 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.194'
runtime 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.194'
//  compile group: 'h2', name: 'h2', version: '0.2.0'

compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager'
//compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-gradle-plugin', version: 
'5.3.6.Final'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core'
```

Comment: Clearly you're missing an `EntityManagerFactory` bean definition.

Comment: But I have two, for each db one: THis should be one of them: @Bean(name = "toEntityManager")
      public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean toEntityManagerFactory

Comment: In the [example](https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7) they use "entityManagerFactory" for the bean name. Can you try it instead of "toEntityManager"?

Comment: Tried before and now as well: error-> Not a managed type: class leadTime.to.TestDataTo. And I tried to solve it this days by adding EntityScan and so on(move in another package)..but no succes.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you have pasted

https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7

One of the darasource is configured as "default" and another one is named. You are creating two "named" beans with `from` and `to` prefixes. 
Change eg `from` database definitions `entityManager` insteed of `fromEntityManager` and it should be fine.

I don't know the internals, but as for common sense, what you try should work, in practice some default datasource is required by app configurator thus the error.

Comment: As @Boris suggested I tried using "entityManagerFactory". The IDE is telling me that this is a default param and if I am using this I get the following error: Not a managed type: class leadTime.to.TestDataTo. And I tried to solve it this days by adding EntityScan and so on..but no succes

Comment: And now I tried using "entityManager" (only) But I have the same error as before: required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

Comment: @Agata - Did you solved your problem? I have the same:(

Comment: @Matley, Check this link and put the classes in different packages (this was my porb): https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/multiple-datasources